# Finding all divisors using math library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write the most efficient code to find divisors of number N:

Here is my code:

```
def divisors(n):
    divs = set()
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if N % i == 0:
            divs.add(i)
            divs.add(int(n/i))
    return divs
```

The problem is when I put 5 it gives me `{1, 2, 5}` when 2 is not divisor of 5

Comment: What is `N`?  That's not the same variable as the `n` passed to `divisors`.  Does `N` perhaps equal 10?

Comment: What is `N`? It should be `n`.

Comment: Apart from the programmatic problem - if you really want to write efficient code, you should have a better strategy than trial and error. Maybe finding all prime factors and creating a product of all powerset elements is probably faster for larger numbers.

Comment: Sorry I wrote a capital N , I meant n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *more* efficient way using list-comprehension

```
def divisors(n):
    divs = [x for x in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n))+1) if n % x == 0]
    opps = [int(n/x) for x in divs] # get divisors > sqrt(n) by division instead
    return list(set(divs + opps))
```

For larger numbers this drastically reduce the complexity from `O(n)` to `O(n^(1/2))`

Comment: Thank you @Rocky Li , your code is most efficient and also fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
def divisors(n):
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if n % x == 0]

print(divisors(5))
```